# Asp.Net Core API - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I have a problem with calling my API in my localhost. I am using Asp.Net MVC Core and my client side is Angular.

In my API side, I think I have added all necessary codes to pass 'Allow-Origin'.
My Startup.cs is below.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value);
    services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(x => x.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddCors();

    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options => {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters{
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false
            };
        });
    services.AddScoped<IAuthRepository, AuthRepository>();
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env){
    if (env.IsDevelopment()){
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin().AllowCredentials());
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

My client side service that calling my API is in below

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

    baseUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/api/auth/';
    userToken: any;

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    login(model: any) {
        const headers = new Headers({'Content-type': 'application/json'});
        const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
        return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'login', model, options).map((response: Response) => {
            const user = response.json();

            if (user) {
                localStorage.setItem('token', user.tokenString);
                this.userToken = user.tokenString;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and my screenshot of error is here:

[image: here].

Comment: i think you will also need to include it in your action as a filter

Comment: there are 500 errors too. there might be some other errors that doesn't let your api reach the CORS check. can you try running your app in debugger?

Answer (score 0):

'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
is not the error.
Your error is an 500 internal server error.

When the application throws an error, it will not add the cors headers.

So if you solve the 500 error it will work.